Do we need a security tag
Recently, on Jan 29 at 16:36 a first question appeared with a security tag. Now after that, there are only 4 questions appeared.
Do we need this tag?

I went ahead and just removed the tag from all affected questions.

No, there is no need for this tag.
Because of those 4 (now 3):

one question was mis-tagged (retagged to cryptanalysis);
one question was migrated;
two questions were closed.

Not to mention the whole point of cryptography is to achieve security, whatever type of security to be achieved. 

Yes, we need this tag!

fill some reasons

